# redirect subdomain to root domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible, having a page like http://example.com/fine-ruby create a subdomain address like http://qr.example.com/fine-ruby for QR Code tracking purposes ?

I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^fine-ruby$ porto-fine-ruby.php [L]
RewriteRule ^lbv-2009$ porto-lbv2009.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tawny10years$ porto-tawny10.php [L]
```

And I'm trying to implement the folowing code (with no success) I picked from other question here on Stackoverflow.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # handles http redirect
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qr\.example\.com$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
 </IfModule>
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.